# Make a PSTN call from softphone using IP PBX module

Tags: voip, telephony

I just bought a PBX IP Module running *Linux IP PBX 2.6 Unitekk*.

I succeed to run VoIP call in my LAN network and also getting the PSTN call into my softphone (XLITE).

Can I make an external call using my softphone through my PSTN line? 
Help me to find the right configuration into my inbound roules or trunks.